# Не могу установить модуль Python 'Discord'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Приложу все, что могу. 
Сразу извиняюсь за название компьютера, так вышло :/

Сама ошибка выскакивает после

`Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error`

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\865B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprxncial_'
     cwd: C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l5nk_7n\aiohttp
Complete output (24 lines):
running dist_info
creating C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info
writing C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\долабеб\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-pzevikws\aiohttp.dist-info'
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\865B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprxncial_' Check the logs for full command output.

Версия Python 3.8.0 64-bit. Система 64-х битная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала `pip install wheel`, затем (но не обязательно) `python setup.py bdist_wheel`